How to page table cell content on Questpdf
I'm using QuestPDF, dynamic content to generate a pdf with several columns, one is the description column that sometimes its content is to big for the pdf to render
table.Cell().ColumnSpan(3).Element(DataCellStyle).PaddingLeft(3).PaddingBottom(15).Text(description);

I tried with
columns.RelativeColumn();

Or adding
EnsureSpace() 

but the content is not being paged, am I missing something?
Edit 1:
table.Cell().PageBreak();

Always showing the same error:
QuestPDF.Elements.DynamicHost.Measure(Size availableSpace)
